# Cannot run a simple application based on catel 4

Tags: c#, mvvm, catel

I am trying to run a simple application based on catel 4 but I didn't even show the window. I don't have errors or warnings

Here is the code of the test application and the application itself.

```
<catel:DataWindow x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <CheckBox Content="Check me to continue" IsChecked="{Binding UserAgreedToContinue, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : DataWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
        : base(DataWindowMode.Custom)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public override string Title { get { return "Just acknowledge"; } }

    public bool UserAgreedToContinue
    {
        get { return GetValue<bool>(UserAgreedToContinueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UserAgreedToContinueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyData UserAgreedToContinueProperty = RegisterProperty("UserAgreedToContinue", typeof(bool));
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does not even start the window?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qjf1khq10y606ql/WpfApplication1.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Enable debug log listener:

```
    public App()
    {
#if DEBUG
        LogManager.AddDebugListener();
#endif
    }
```

It immediately shows you what's wrong:

> The view model of the view 'WpfApplication1.MainWindow' could not be
>   resolved. Make sure to customize the IViewModelLocator or register the
>   view and view model manually

This is because you don't have the namespaces that are usually used in MVVM. You can of course [customize everything](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Locators+and+naming+conventions) but since you are a beginner, I recommend the following actions:

1. Move view model to WpfApplication1.ViewModels namespace
2. Move view to WpfApplication1.Views namespace (both xaml and code-behind)
3. Change startup uri in App.xaml to "/Views/MainWindow.xaml"

I also strongly recommend that you read the [getting started guide](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Getting+started).